# Google Play Billing Library 3.0.3 and 4.0.0 does not work with Gsuite accounts

Tags: android, in-app-billing, play-billing-library

I am using Google Play Billing Library 3.0.3 and 4.0.0.
On GSuite accounts, the `BillingClient.startConnection()` allways get the error message:

"Google Play In-app Billing API version is less than 3".

It only happen with all GSuite for Education accounts, with gmail.com accounts is allways fine. I have tried with different devices, and it only happens  with Gsuite accounts.

Any idea why?